What axiomatic system does AlphaGeometry use?
In January 2024, researchers from DeepMind announced AlphaGeometry, a software able to solve geometry problems from the International Mathematical Olympiad using a combination of AI techniques and a formal language engine (this subject has already been discussed here on MO).
Their paper Solving olympiad geometry without human demonstrations does a good job at explaining the methodology (the so-called neuro-symbolic approach), however, I find it quite elusive regarding the formalism they rely on to model geometry.
The paper mentions the use of a specialized language used in GEX, JGEX, MMP/Geometer 13 and GeoLogic, but I couldn't find relevant information about the formalism adopted in these tools (nor is it clear whether AlphaGeometry is actually using one of these tools or one of its own).
On the mathematical side, some modern formalisms used to tackle planar geometry are Hilbert axioms or Tarski axioms.
Question: Is AlphaGeometry based on one of the aforementioned formalisms (Hilbert, Tarski) and if not, which formal system does it rely on?

maybe helpful https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/19fg9rx/some_perspective_on_alphageometry/

@mathoverflowUser This is interesting regarding the strategy used to solve problems, but it doesn't mention the formalism / axiomatization used in the first place.

The AlphaGeometry paper indicates that they made some enhancements to the GEX language, and they give some examples of the language, but they don't give a complete specification of the formalism in their paper or in any of the supplementary materials, as far as I can see. I suspect your best bet is to contact the authors directly.

I know this doesn't directly answer the question, but I think this question is going to end up similar to "what axiomatic system does WolframAlpha use?". Math software usually doesn't explicitly mention the formal system justifying them.

@ChristopherKing I agree with you partially, but the AlphaGeometry paper does speak of a "symbolic deduction engine" that uses a particular formal language for elementary geometry, as well as a fixed list of rules for symbolic deductions. In this sense, there is a specific "formalism" that they are using, and it ought to be possible to say precisely what the syntax of the language is, and what rules the symbolic deduction engine is using. But you're right that a "formalism" in this sense need not be an axiomatic system for Euclidean geometry in the sense of Hilbert.
